# How can I get listen the request that has been made in a web thtough InAppWebView in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, webview, flutter-inappwebview

I have been requested to work on an app which is basically a WebView with the web embedded. Everything seems to work fine but There is an issue to be resolved.

They need a native loader for every loading process that is happening on the website.

I am using the plugin: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_inappwebview which catches loads of the URLs. So partially is done, but there is one thing remaining. Some request doesn't refresh the screen on the website. So I am not able to listen to it and it feels like nothing is happening whenever something is been working in the background to fetch data in a searching scenario or whenever the filter is been used.

Is there any possible way to listen to that internal process that happens in the background to show to the user a loader?

I know that this loader should be implemented on the web, but It is what it is...

I have tried all the functionalities that inappwebview offer but none of them seems to solve the issue.

Comment: Could you find a solution?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `androidShouldInterceptRequest` field to intercept HTTP webView requests.

```
InAppWebView(
  androidShouldInterceptRequest: // <--
      (controller, request) async {
    print(request);
  },
  ...
  initialOptions: InAppWebViewGroupOptions(
    android: AndroidInAppWebViewOptions(
      useShouldInterceptRequest: true, // <--
    ),
    ...
 )
```

`useShouldInterceptRequest`: Set to true to be able to listen at the `androidShouldInterceptRequest` event. The default value is false